# Deleting a row from table view and server also in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, localhost

I am trying to delete a row from table view and I want to delete that from the server to I am using localhost as my server

my delete URL is [LocalHost](http://localhost:8080/hub/business/fun/%7Bid%7D) in id place I have to send "id" and I am getting that through did select of  table view and I am passing through that URL and I am unable to remove from the server while doing this process

please help me is there any changes in my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {

       // getting id //
        id1 = "\(arrdata[indexPath.row].id)"
        print(id1)

        self.arrdata.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/hub/business/fun/=%@",id1 as CVarArg)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            do{if error == nil{
                self.arrdata = try JSONDecoder().decode([jsonstruct3].self, from: data!)

                for mainarr in self.arrdata{
                    //                    print(mainarr.name,":",mainarr.capital,":",mainarr.alpha3Code)
                    //                    print(data)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                print("Error in get json data")
                print(error)
            }

            }.resume()

        tableView.reloadData()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer, Please follow it.

1. First of all, for deleting the record from app side - You need to
   delete it from Array and also need to remove the cell from
   tableview.
2. For deleting the record from server side, You need to call an API to
   let server know about which data server will delete.

I checked your code and found that deleting the record from app side seems correct but while calling an API - I guess you need to pass some more info to server. May be you would like to pass Header, HTTP Method, Parameters etc. You can do all this things with URLRequest. You just passed the URL in your code, so instead of pass the URL directly please try to pass the URLRequest.

> And after following the answer, please try below code to check exact
>   what your are getting back from server side.

```
if let url = URL(string: "Your API URL here") {
            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
            urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST" //Can be any as "GET", "PUT"
            urlRequest.addValue("Bearer \("token")", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization") //Based on your back-end requirements.
            let params = ["id": "5"] //Based on your back-end requirements.
            urlRequest.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
                if error == nil, let jsonData = data {
                    do {
                        if let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
                            print(jsonResponse)
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
```

Comment: Thank you please share source code of like that so I can modify according to my requirement OR you can share any post related to this

Comment: @vamsi I Updated my answer, Please check now. And about which header, paramters, and HTTP method need to pass to server that you can ask to your back-end developer who developed this API.

Comment: @vamsi, I updated my whole answer based on your requirements.

Comment: Argument labels '(string:, _:)' do not match any available overloads I am getting this error in this line I am not able to figure it out what type of error it is, its coming in this line.                   guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/hubnr/company/fun/=%@",id1 as CVarArg) else { return }

Comment: @Gopali am sorry for taking too long  I have tried your scenario but not working and where you are adding my dynamic id to my url and I have tried in this scenario as posting my url in this way please correct me if I am wrong             if let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/hub/company/fun/"+id1) {

Comment: @vamsi like this create the URL = URL(string: ("Your API URL here" + id1))

Comment: ya I figured it by adding + symbol after end of url                 guard let url = URL(string:"http://localhost:8080/hub/company/fun/"+id1) else { return }
and working good and think  we are doing mistake of using post method instead of DETETE is I have got error like this {
    error = "Method Not Allowed";
    exception = "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException";
    message = "Request method 'POST' not supported";
    path = "/hub/company/fun/2";
    status = 405;
    timestamp = 1562302486393;

Comment: @vamsi, Its depend on your back-end team how prepared the API, and thats why in my answer I mentioned that HTTP Method, Headers, Parameters are depend on your requirements.

Comment: @vamsi, woohoo, Your welcome. and if you find that my answer helps you to track the issue then please accept it and upvote. Thanks